# do multiple things with sqlite3 resultset

Tags: bash, sqlite, resultset

i have a sqlite3 database on a ubuntu host. i would like to start a bash script to manipulate some contained data.

basically, i have the sql statement figured out. i would like to process multiple commands with the results of this query (i.e. the resultset). the query spans multiple tables to get the full data i need.

for each returned row, i would like to write certain fields to a text file (for later use) and once completed, i would then like to update a row. this update is for 1 field in 1 table.

currently, i only have the following which produces the required output file of all the rows:

```
sqlite3 database.db
.output xbmc_music_lastplayed_toitunes.txt

SELECT s.strTitle, art.strArtist, a.strAlbum, s.iTimesPlayed, s.lastplayed
FROM song as s, album as a, artist as art
WHERE s.idAlbum = a.idAlbum
AND s.idArtist = art.idArtist
AND s.iTimesPlayed > 0
```

i would like to be able to complete both actions from 1 resultset, if its possible. hoping someone could provide a way forward. i am used to dealing with programmatic processing of db's, i.e. with PHP, but in this case its being done more natively to the sqlite3 engine itself.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your sql statements(or `dot` command) in `query.sql`.

```
$ cat query.sql | sqllite3 database.db
```

or

```
$ sqlite3 database.db
sqlite> .read query.sql
```

I prefer the first option. Because there's no interaction.